# Schema for storing events in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, sorry if i am not so specific and i don't know how to explain this better but i have a question with Database and columns, like i use this code:
FUNCTION:

```
public function getAll(IPlayer $p1) {
         $teste = "- Testando";
    $a = $this->db->query("SELECT group_concat(jogador2 SEPARATOR '".$teste."' )  as my_amigos FROM amigos WHERE jogador='".$p1->getName()."' group by jogador");
     $b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a);
     return $b;
    }
```

EVENT:

```
     $msg = null;
                    foreach($this->plugin->getAll($player) as $friend => $p) {
                    #   var_dump($this->getAll($player)["my_amigos"]);
                
                            $msg .= "$p";
            
 
                    } 
                    $form->addButton("$msg", "");
```

and i have this on database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMrCi.png)
and when i run the event i receive this: [RiquelmeMaciel- TestandoBunda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJFWM.png)
but i need to do a function for all players in that colum like i need to get

```
RiquelmeMaciel - Testando
Bunda - Testando
```

Obs: i don't know how to do that please help, like i just need to get if this player on that column is online.
SORRY about me and my english, and i don't have an idea to explain better, srr.
If none knows what i mean, i just want to get people by people in query not all in one understand? of the player..

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Don't worry about putting tags in the title. There's a special field for that which, as a bonus, is searchable by people looking for problems to help with or solve.

Comment: Omg, i don't understand 1 word that you say to me! lol

Comment: PHP core documentation is [available in many languages](http://php.net/docs.php) if English isn't the best for you. It covers how to do this properly.